# Replace numeric values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

**Problem**: Polluted Dataframe. 
Details: Frame consists of NaNs string values which i know the meaning of and numeric values. 
**Task**: Replaceing the numeric values with NaNs 
**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'cdf', 1], ['k', 'sum', 'some'], [1000, np.nan, 'nothing']])
```

out:

```
      0    1        2
0   abc  cdf        1
1     k  sum     some
2  1000  NaN  nothing
```

**Attempt 1** (Does not work, because regex only looks at string cells)

```
df.replace({'\d+': np.nan}, regex=True)
```

out:

```
      0    1        2
0   abc  cdf        1
1     k  sum     some
2  1000  NaN  nothing
```

**Preliminary Solution**

```
val_set = set()
[val_set.update(i) for i in df.values]

def dis_nums(myset):
    str_s = set()
    num_replace_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(myset)):
        val = myset.pop()
        if type(val) == str:
            str_s.update([val])
        else:
            num_replace_dict.update({val:np.nan})
    return str_s, num_replace_dict

strs, rpl_dict = dis_nums(val_set)

df.replace(rpl_dict, inplace=True)
```

out:

```
     0    1        2
0  abc  cdf      NaN
1    k  sum     some
2  NaN  NaN  nothing
```

**Question**
Is there any easier/ more pleasant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a round-conversion to `str` to replace the values and back.

```
df.astype('str').replace({'\d+': np.nan, 'nan': np.nan}, regex=True).astype('object')
#This makes sure already existing np.nan are not lost
```

**Output**

```
    0   1   2
0   abc cdf NaN
1   k   sum some
2   NaN NaN nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to go through each columns, and check each item. If it is an integer or float then replace it with np.nan. It can be done easily with map function applied on the column.

you can change the condition of the `if` to incorporate any data type u want.

```
for x in df.columns:
    df[x] = df[x].map(lambda item : np.nan if type(item) == int or type(item) == float else item)
```

This is a naive approach and there have to be better solutions than this.!!